# Which Drupal module can be used for announcing policy (Terms & Conditions) changes?

Tags: drupal

Is there any Drupal module available to announce changes to the terms of use of a (Drupal) site, and only show it 1 time to each registered user?

If the terms would change later on again, then show something similar for the updated terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [Legal](https://www.drupal.org/project/legal) module. Some details about it (from it's project page):

> Displays your Terms & Conditions to users who want to register, and requires that they accept the T&C before their registration is accepted.
>
> If T&Cs are changed users with an existing account will be asked to accept the new version, and will not be able to log in until they have.
>
> Terms & Conditions can be displayed as styled text, or in a scroll box.
>
> [image]

Head over to the module's project page for even more details.